# Testing whether a path in a directed graph does not cause cycles

Tags: javascript, graph, cyclic-graph

This is a different question from what I have found so far related to cycles in graph as they relate to finding cycles in general but I need to find a cycle in a specific situation.

Consider the following graph:

```
n1: [n2]
n2: [n3]
n3: [n4]
n4: [n5, n2]
n5: []
```

This function should only return `true` when testing for the path from `n4` to `n2`.
In my situation I don't consider a cycle other paths because they are "safe" to render in the UI. However, if I would try to render the association between in `n4` to `n2` I would recreate the whole path recursively.

So far I came up with the following:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} target The target node
 * @param {Record<string, string[]>} g The graph
 * @param {string} key The current key
 * @returns {boolean} true when going from `key` to `target` would create a cycle.
 */
hasCycle(target, g, key) {
  if (target === key) {
    return true;
  }
  
  const neighbors: string[] = [];
  Object.keys(g).forEach(prop => {
    if (g[prop].includes(key)) {
      neighbors.push(prop);
    }
  });
  
  for (const neighbor of neighbors) {
    if (neighbor === key) {
      return true;
    }
    if (hasCycle(target, g, neighbor)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This works in most cases except for the following:

```
n1: [n2]
n2: [n3]
n3: [n2]
```

When I test `hasCycle('n2', {...}, 'n3')` this function returns `true` as the cycle exist but for the purpose of the UI I am building I am not consider it a cycle just yet (I would if I would be testing for `n3` -> `n2`).

**Edit**, to better illustrate the problem. Imagine rendering in the UI a JSON schema as a data structure. The schema has properties that can be either scalars or other schemes. These schemes can reference each other in properties which at some point will cause a cycle (when you represent it as a graph). The reason I am not considering `n2` -> `n3` a cycle for the purpose of the visualization is because it is safe for me to render the schema that is defined as `n3` under a `n2` property but if I would expand a property of `n3` schema that has a reference to `n2` would cause a recursive rendering of the whole tree.

```
- schema 1
  - prop1 (scalar)
  - prop2 (ref to schema 2)
- schema 2
  - prop3 (ref to schema 3)
- schema 3
  - prop4 (ref to schema 2)
```

In the UI  you need to expand complex properties (referenced schemes) to see their properties. When the user expands `prop4` it would recreate the whole `schema 2` -> `prop3` -> `schema 3` -> `prop4` in a cycle which would end with throwing an error. The function I am trying to find is to tell me that `prop4` cannot be expanded.

Comment: I prepared the following fiddle to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jarrodek/50kd2b17/46/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*going from `key` to `target` would create a cycle*". Your graph is static, right? It either has a cycle or it doesn't, and a cycle may contain certain edges or nodes. Are you trying to find a cycle in the graph that contains `n2` and `n4`?

Comment: @Bergi It is static in this example. The whole graph is generated depending on user input. The `key` represents the current node and the `target` represents the path I can render. I want to render in the UI information that this path is recursive so it cannot be rendered.

Comment: What is a "*recursive path*"? A path that contains a cycle, i.e. contains the same node  multiple times? And no, a single `target` does not represent a path, there might be multiple (or no) paths between the source and the target node.

Comment: @Bergi "recursive path" as a cycle. My mistake, I mean `target` is the target node and the path is between the two nodes. I believe the jsfiddle I linked in the first comment well illustrate the problem.

Comment: A path between two different nodes is not a cycle. I don't understand the fiddle either. It has some "expected" values, but no explanation *why* these would be expected. Also I don't get why the path `n2 -> n3` would have a different expected result than the path `n3 -> n2`.

Comment: @Bergi The "expected" means that the result of calling the function should equal to the value I set as the 3rd value in the array. The why is no important to helping me solve that but if you this helps you then I am rendering a complex data structure (think JSON schema or similar) where you can expand a property of the schema which can be another schema (if not a scalar property). These properties can be recursive (in graph terminology is a cycle) so rendering such a property would cause recursion and eventually an error.

Comment: So actually you are doing a graph traversal, and you wan to find whether traversing an edge would *close* a cycle to subgraph of nodes that you already visited?

Comment: @Bergi yes, actually.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with your implementation is that this doesn't actually depend only on the current key, but rather on the path from starting point to the current key.

Comment: @Bergi Just to clarify, in my case in a simple graph with two nodes, each referencing another (A -> B, B -> A) I need to consider `A -> B` as not a cycle but `B -> A` as a cycle.

Comment: "*When the user expands `prop4` it would recreate the whole `schema 2` -> `prop3` -> `schema 3` -> `prop4` in a cycle*" - I don't follow. Wouldn't you just render the `schema 2` there - collapsed? And then the user would have to expand `prop3` again? This could recurse arbitrarily, without leading to an error.

Comment: That you want to consider `B -> A` as closing the cycle but not `A -> B` depends on you starting in `A`. If you had started at node `B`, you'd get the opposite result. Also for your larger example, consider `schema 1` having a `prop5` that references `schema 3`. Now its either the `schema 2 -prop3-> schema 3` edge or the `schema3 -prop4 -> schema 2` that you don't want to expand, **depending** on whether you had previously expanded `schema 1 -prop2 -> schema 2` or `schema 1 -prop5-> schema 3`.

Comment: @Bergi Generally you are right and I considered this. However, for the purpose of the application I should point out recursion in the data (that's one of the requirements). So I still need to know when exactly a cycle occurs.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, now I realize the path is important and I need to consider the direction to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Good :-) At which point the solution just becomes `currentPath.includes(nextTarget)`

Comment: @Bergi I used your advice and now it all works perfectly. Retrospectively, it was dumb not to think about the direction. I guess I am tired trying to make this work for 2 days...